# Retag request: [keytab] -> [kerberos]

Tags: support, retag-request

[keytab](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/keytab) is a worthless tag and should be merged into its obvious parent [kerberos](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kerberos) both now and in the future.

It's possible, though unlikely, that keytab will take on some other meaning in the future. In the meantime, keytab is [proper subset](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/keytab+-kerberos) of kerberos.

Comment: There are 10 questions tagged with keytab, and _all_ of them also have the kerberos tag.

Comment: yup- Keytab should be deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[keytab](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/keytab) has been merged and synonymized to [kerberos](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kerberos).